# Required Params Validations in Rails 5 API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activemodel, rails-api

Thank you for looking onto this. I have a rails 5 API application. I am using ActiveModel Validations to validate params. 
I need to validate the keys of params. ie. all the keys are mandatory to keep the structure of request unique, but it can be blank(ie. the values)
I know the

```
validates :key presence: true
```

validation, but it is checking there is a value for that. As i said, it can have blank values.

I am using params.permit so that additional keys are not allowed

```
include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates :key1, presence: true
def initialize
  @key1 = "val"
  @key2 = "val2"
  params.permit(:key1,:key2)
end
```

I need to compel the user to do requests with all the parameters with blanks allowed

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about you just fill all missed parameters with blank values?

Comment: that is great thought! but, i need to know whether there is something like this in rails active model validation

Comment: Yea, there is `allow_blank` option, but according to documentation`presence` validator `uses the blank? method to check if the value is either nil or a blank string`, meanwhile `allow_blank` option `will let validation pass if the attribute's value is blank?, like nil or an empty string for example`. Just saying, use it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you should add the allow_blank options to your model like this:

`validates :key presence: true, :allow_blank => true`

Hope it can help

Answer (score 0):

From the doc you need to specify allow_blank like :

`validates :key1, :presence => true, :uniqueness => { :allow_blank => true, :case_sensitive => false }`

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below:

`validates :key, presence: true, allow_blank: true`

allow_blank:
`The :allow_blank option is similar to the :allow_nil option.This option will let validation pass if the attribute's value is blank?, like nil or an empty string for example.`

**Note**: `nil` values will be allowed

Comment: allow_blank: true 
also bypass if there is no such key pair. It does not consider presence: true

Comment: @AliAkbar it shouldn't. can you check the exact error?